# My answer is being censored

Tags: support

I wrote

> Avoid Revolut like the plague. It has two gigantic red flags: one, the ties to Gazprom (the father of the CEO, Nikolay Mironovich Storonsky is Deputy General Director of Science for Gazprom Promgaz since 2017, and First Deputy General Director for Science Gazprom Promgaz). Two, it dabbles in crypto and all crypto are scam see for example [this](https://english.elpais.com/science-tech/2022-07-07/jorge-stolfi-technologically-bitcoin-and-blockchain-technology-is-garbage.html). No company that touches crypto can be trusted especially not with holding money. Revolut is also handing out free money and while in itself such marketing ploys are not unusual together with the first two it makes you very strongly wonder where the money is coming from. It's operating at a loss and only by constantly raising money does it stay afloat.

and this is being censored at https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/175962/4188

It is sourced, it is factual and it is useful. It's being suppressed, of course it is.

Answer (score 11):

That piece I deleted - is not an answer.

It has nothing to do with the question the OP asked, and is a rant on your behalf.

You are well aware of the site rules, you have been here long enough to know that

- this is not censorship
- this site can and does encourage editing to make posts clearer, remove personal opinion and rants, and aid in answering the question as asked
- when you post here, you explicitly consent to your posts being edited for the community good

Comment: this is censorship

Answer (score 11):

Your post is half a rant, half an answer. A mod had edited out the rant and left in the answer. You edited the rant back in, so an other mod edited the rant out again.

This is not to censor you, it is to make the post follow the rules of the site where rants are not acceptable.

A comment with the warning is enough, no need to have it as half an answer.

Comment: it is to censorship.

Comment: This is not a free speech site, but it is a site with rules and you know you have to stick to those rules if you want to post here. You did not, your post was edited so the part that kept those rules was allowed to stay, (much of) the rest stayed as a comment. If you are not happy with the decisions of the moderators on TSE, you can go higher up and ask for their opinion. Remember that if you do not stick to the rules we can and do suspend you.